# Store and access whole collection with over 5000 documents

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have Firestore objects with potentially some big tables attached. I have to store and access tables that may be over 5000 rows, so my first thought was to store them as a subcollection of my object.

The issue is that it takes quite some time to retrieve the 5000 rows in my Cloud Function, and as well the bill might become high since I get billed of 5000 reads every time the data is retrieved.

Is there some way to store the subcollection so it's "cached"?
Would that make sense to store these tables in files or even CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preload the data from Firestore into an SDK that supports persistence, you can [use data bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles) to do so, for example by [serving the 5,000 documents as a single bundle from a CDN or a Cloud Storage bucket](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles).

However, the Admin SDKs that you use in Cloud Functions don't support disk persistence, so you'd have to load the file from the CDN/Storage for each new instance, which may also be a slow or expensive operation.

If the data doesn't change frequently, consider if you an include the data bundle in the Cloud Functions source/build folder itself and load it from there. That'd make it part of the container instance that your function runs on, so the read would be free and data access would be local so really fast.